# User doesn't stay logged in in a Laravel 8 app

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to find out why the below code won't work. I found no other questions that had an answer that actually worked.

Login controller code:

```
public function loginuser(Request $request)
{
    $email = $request->input('email');
    $password = $request->input('password');

    $credentials = array(
        'email'     => $email,
        'password'  => $password
    );

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return view('index.home');
    } else {
        return view('auth.login');
    }
}
```

My session config:

```
<?php

  use Illuminate\Support\Str;

 return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Session Driver
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default session "driver" that will be used on
| requests. By default, we will use the lightweight native driver but
| you may specify any of the other wonderful drivers provided here.
|
| Supported: "file", "cookie", "database", "apc",
|            "memcached", "redis", "dynamodb", "array"
|
*/

'driver' => 'database',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Lifetime
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
| to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
| to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
|
*/

'lifetime' => 10080,

'expire_on_close' => false,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Encryption
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option allows you to easily specify that all of your session data
| should be encrypted before it is stored. All encryption will be run
| automatically by Laravel and you can use the Session like normal.
|
*/

'encrypt' => true,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session File Location
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the native session driver, we need a location where session
| files may be stored. A default has been set for you but a different
| location may be specified. This is only needed for file sessions.
|
*/

'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Database Connection
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
| connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
| correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
|
*/

'connection' => 'mysql',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Database Table
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table we
| should use to manage the sessions. Of course, a sensible default is
| provided for you; however, you are free to change this as needed.
|
*/

'table' => 'sessions',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cache Store
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| While using one of the framework's cache driven session backends you may
| list a cache store that should be used for these sessions. This value
| must match with one of the application's configured cache "stores".
|
| Affects: "apc", "dynamodb", "memcached", "redis"
|
*/

'store' => env('SESSION_STORE', null),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Sweeping Lottery
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
| rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
| happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
|
*/

'lottery' => [2, 100],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Name
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may change the name of the cookie used to identify a session
| instance by ID. The name specified here will get used every time a
| new session cookie is created by the framework for every driver.
|
*/

'cookie' => env(
    'SESSION_COOKIE',
    Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
| be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
| your application but you are free to change this when necessary.
|
*/

'path' => '/',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Domain
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
| in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
| available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
|
*/

'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| HTTPS Only Cookies
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
| to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
| the cookie from being sent to you if it can not be done securely.
|
*/

'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', null),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| HTTP Access Only
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Setting this value to true will prevent JavaScript from accessing the
| value of the cookie and the cookie will only be accessible through
| the HTTP protocol. You are free to modify this option if needed.
|
*/

'http_only' => true,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Same-Site Cookies
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option determines how your cookies behave when cross-site requests
| take place, and can be used to mitigate CSRF attacks. By default, we
| will set this value to "lax" since this is a secure default value.
|
| Supported: "lax", "strict", "none", null
|
*/

'same_site' => null,

];
```

What can I try to fix this?

Comment: Have overriden the default loginController of AUTH?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean is the loginController the same as it was created by AUTH or you have made custom one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to generate a session after a successful login. In your case, you are returning the view without saving the user in the session.

```
if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
    $request->session()->regenerate();
    return view('index.home');
} else {
    return view('auth.login');
}
```

Comment: Hey now i get this error Session store not set on request.

Comment: check this solution https://www.edureka.co/community/79946/error-laravel-session-store-not-set-on-request

Comment: Thanks, it worked but i still have problem it now logs in for like sometime and then crashes again

Comment: change session driver database to file